# /etc/cron.d not executing the script

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron

I have a test script that I want to run periodically. I have created a file in the `/etc/cron.d` directory named `my_test.cron`.

```
#ls -l /etc/cron.d/my_test.cron
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  81 Sep 24  2020 my_test.cron
#cat /etc/cron.d/my_test.cron
00 02 * * * root /usr/bin/my_dir/test_wrapper.sh > /var/log/clamav.err 2>&1
```

I could see that the cron task is not invoked. There are no logs available in the `log.err` file.
However the script works fine when executed manually,
Permissions for the wrapper script:->

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.2K Sep 24 2020 /usr/bin/my_dir/test_wrapper.sh
```

when I tailed the Syslog, I could only see and nothing about my cron :->

```
Jul 14 00:02:01 my-test-vm CRON[15891]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: That syslog entry looks like it comes from `/etc/cron.d/sysstat` rather than from your own file. BTW is the file name *actually* named `my_test_cron`? cron places some restrictions about filenames as detailed in the man pages (`my_test_cron` is OK, but `my_test.cron` would not be for example).

Comment: @steeldriver
Thanks that helped, the file name had a dot(.) and as per the man page the cron file with extensions are skipped

Comment: So the question doesn't make sense as written - please [edit] it to reflect the actual file name

Answer (score -1):

<s>files in `/etc/cron.d` (and `/etc/cron.*` directories) are meant to be executed, those are not `crontab` file.</s>

- files in `/etc/cron.*` directories are meant to be executed, those are not `crontab` file.
- files in `/etc/cron.d` are crontab files.

alternative solution can be :

either edit `/etc/crontab` with

```
00 02 * * * root /usr/bin/my_dir/test_wrapper.sh > /var/log/clamav.err 2>&1
```

or as root, using `crontab -e` add following line

```
00 02 * * * /usr/bin/my_dir/test_wrapper.sh > /var/log/clamav.err 2>&1
```